# OPENSSH - unable to connect local windows through ssh

Tags: openssh

I installed openssh server using below url,

https://howtech.tv/basics/how-to-install-openssh-to-windows/

It installed successfully on my local machine which is windows 8.1 and my login is domain login. But when i am trying to connect to ssh server, it is throwing error saying "Permission denied" and after three attempts it comes out of ssh.

```
ssh username@myhostname
```

It asks for password but does not connect.

```
username@myhostname's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
username@myhostname's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
username@myhostname's password:
Authentication failed.

C:\Users\username>
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: That looks like an extremely old, out of date, unmaintained version of openssh . I recommend not using it.

Answer (score 1):

The program `sshwindows` on sourceforge is extrremely old and seems to be unmaintained. I strongly receommend against using it.

Also, Windows 8.1 has been unsupported for over a year. You should consider moving to Windows 10 which already includes a (beta) version of SSH supported by Microsoft.

The WinSCP site has instructions on how to install the Microsoft version from github:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server and Microsoft have documentation on an alternative way to install: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Answer (score 0):

Install OpenSSH for Windows 8 or 7  from:
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases

OpenSSH-Win64.zip or
OpenSSH-Win32.zip

Extract it on any path.
Make a copy of the file 'sshd_config_default' and rename it to sshd_config.
Edit this file and uncomment 'ListenAddress 0.0.0.0' line and save the file.
Run cmd with administrator role, go to the above folder path and type the following to install OpenSSH as a service: "sc create sshservice binpath=sshd.exe"
It will show service installed successfully.
Make sure to add this folder in the path environment variable.
Now start this sshservice service from services.msc.